# Magnetic field of solenoid from superposition of loops

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I was thinking if it could it be possible to calculate the field inside a solenoid $$B = \mu_0 n I$$ using the principle of superposition for the magnetic field for $N$ circular loops centered on the same axis.

I don't know if it can be useful but from Jackson's book I found the formulae for the magnetic filed generated by a loop for every point $(r,\theta, \phi)$ in space, which are quite complicated:

\begin{align*}
&B_r = \frac{\mu_0 I a}{2r}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (2n+1)!!}{2^n n!}\frac{r_<^{2n+1}}{r_>^{2n+2}}P_{2n+1}(\cos\theta)\\[5pt]
&B_\theta = -\frac{\mu_0 I a^2}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(2n+1)!!}{2^n(n+1)!}\left\{\begin{matrix} -\left(\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}\right)\frac{1}{a^3}\left(\frac{r}{a}\right)^{2n} \\ \frac{1}{r^3}\left(\frac{a}{r}\right)^{2n}\end{matrix}\right\}P^1_{2n+1}(\cos\theta)
\end{align*}

which are calculated by the vector potential  $$A_\phi = -\frac{\mu_0 I a}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (2n-1)!!}{2^n (n+1)!}\frac{r_<^{2n+1}}{r_>^{2n+2}}P^1_{2n+1}(\cos\theta)$$ 
where $P^m_l(\cdot)$ are the associated Legendre polynomials, $a$ is the radius of the loop, $r_< (r_>)$ is the smaller (larger) of $a$ and $r$. For the angular part of the field, the upper line in curly brackets holds for $r<a$ and the lower for $r>a$.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Is it possibile to evaluate the formula for the magnetic field inside a solenoid by superposition of magnetic field of N loops? And if it is possible, how is done?

Comment: I think, the simple answer to your question is 'yes', to a good approximation. How is it done? You say it yourself: you superimpose (add up) the fields of the individual loops.

Comment: @flaudemus It baffles me how such a simple solution $B=\mu_0 n I$ can arise from such a complicated expression. I was curious to see if it was possible to derive analytically the result starting from Jackson's solution. My mathematical skills aren't enough to approach this!

Comment: *It baffles me how such a simple solution...can arise from such a complicated expression* I think the same thing about Taylor series :)